# data table header height increased after showing /hiding the columns in IE8 browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, datatables

We are dynamically hiding/showing  the data table column (using datatable plugin as well Fixed Column.js plugin)

After hiding the columns,it will increase the table header height  in IE8 browser only.

This is code we are using to hide. "index" is column index.

```
//$datatable is datatable object

     if(some condition)
    {
                        $datatable.fnSetColumnVis(index, false);
                    }
                    else {
                        $datatable.fnSetColumnVis(index, true);
    }
```

This issue seems to be FixedColumns.js(2.0.3 version). we are using FixedColumns in our data table.

how to maintain the same table header height for all cases after showing /hiding the columns in data table

Comment: (per request) - sorry, dont have IE8 anywhere anymore, impossible for me to try out. Using `fnSetColumnVis` myself on several sites, never heard a specific IE8 complain. Have you tried forcing the height, like `th { height : 16px !important; }` ?? Just a suggestion. 16px is also just a suggestion.

Comment: @david thanks for your prompt response.anyway we are using IE8 browser in our project.will try your suggestion and will research further

Comment: Also try `th { white-space:nowrap !important; }` perhaps IE8 makes a new line/break in the header because the column is set visible before the width(s) is (re)calculated (??)